# Replace password in Websphere datasource during runtime

Tags: websphere, change-password

After I look up the datasource in Websphere 8 with application code can I set its password to something other than what is in the config file? (Where I get that other password is not of concern here, I just have it.)
This should all happen during runtime and I don't want to write the password to a config file, just do this replacement in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can supply the user name and password as arguments to the [DataSource.getConnection(user, password)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method.

If you obtain your data source with a resource reference, you will need to ensure that its authentication type is [APPLICATION](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/Resource.AuthenticationType.html#APPLICATION), not CONTAINER. (CONTAINER is the default for a resource reference that does not specify).  Here is an example,

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/myDataSource", authenticationType = AuthenticationType.APPLICATION)
DataSource myDataSource;

...
Connection con = myDataSource.getConnection(user, password);
```